# Coexistence of ID And CLASS on an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm writing some HTML that uses jQuery and CSS.  I want to use a system where I have `class=""` to manage the CSS and have an `id=""` to have jQuery reference.  I can't just call the jQuery by class name because I have several div boxes of the same class.

All together, is it OK to do something like the following?

```
<p id="id" class="css">Text</p>
```

Also, if it is ok, is it proper to do it that way?
Is there a better way I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining `class` and `id` is OK as long as the `id` is unique.

Use `#` for id and `.` for class.

Like

```html
<p id="id" class="css">Text</p>
```

```
$('#id').text();
$('.class').css('color','blue');
```

If you don't want to name each div with a unique `ID` you can also get the div using class just get the index

Comment: there you can just comment so i can change not to downvote right away i just write the code hre so i dont have IDE to tell me i got it wrong

Comment: comment seems to be use to make the code better not the downvote as much as i know..

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks for the help!

Comment: glad to help please review the code i gave you need to put the `selector` inside `''` for example if you want to select and element with id `id` you use `$('#id')`

Comment: would have worked if you just pointed it out instead of downvoting its not helpin

Comment: @intboolstring im happy to help happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple classes and one unique id on a single element like you show. However, you can also target a specific element by class with [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

Note that the array is 0 based meaning that `.eq(0)` will select the first element form the matched array while `.eq(1)` will select the second, etc...

```js
$('.someClass').eq(2).html('this div was targeted by class and changed with jQuery');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someClass">some text</div><br>
<div class="someClass">some text</div><br>
<div class="someClass">some text</div><br>
<div class="someClass">some text</div><br>
```